# how to get records which contains only not null values without mention column name where clause?

Tags: mysql

I want to filter records which contains only not null values without giving where cluase.

Ex:
I am having a table like below

id, colum_1, column_2, column_3.... colunm_100

Is any option getting records with not null with out specify in where clause**strong text**(Select * from table where column is not null, column_ is not null)

Comment: What is the problem in using where clause?

Comment: @AnkitSharma probably is too long to write and the OP is lazy.

Comment: there are more than 150 columns, So it is little difficult to form query.

Comment: can any one please help me?

Comment: It's a text editor question : you'll need to write the query with the 150 columns.

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly type the column names or make use of the result from this query

```
set @sql:='';
select max(cols) from
(
select @sql:=concat(@sql,column_name,' is not null and ') as cols 
 from information_schema.columns
where table_name='table_name'
) as t;
```